MariaDB Slave not updating from Master
No errors are reported but changes on the master, even after waiting over night are not showing up in the slave.
Suggestions greatly appreciated.
Master Server Version = 10.6.19-MariaDB-log

SHOW MASTER STATUS;

File = master1-bin.000002,
Position = 123151193,
Binlog_Do_DB = ,
Binlog_Ignore_DB = 

SHOW databases;
Database = information_schema
Database = sandbox1_joomla1



Slave Server Properties

Slave Server Version = 10.5.22-MariaDB

SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
Slave_IO_State = Waiting for master to send event,
Master_Host = ***********,
Master_User = ***********,
Master_Port = 3306,
Connect_Retry = 10,
Master_Log_File = master1-bin.000002,
Read_Master_Log_Pos = 123151193,
Relay_Log_File = mariadb-relay-bin.000006,
Relay_Log_Pos = 123142209,
Relay_Master_Log_File = master1-bin.000002,
Slave_IO_Running = Yes,
Slave_SQL_Running = Yes,
Replicate_Do_DB = sandbox_joomla1,
Replicate_Ignore_DB = ,
Replicate_Do_Table = ,
Replicate_Ignore_Table = ,
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table = ,
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table = ,
Last_Errno = 0,
Last_Error = ,
Skip_Counter = 0,
Exec_Master_Log_Pos = 123151193,
Relay_Log_Space = 123142569,
Until_Condition = None,
Until_Log_File = ,
Until_Log_Pos = 0,
Master_SSL_Allowed = No,
Master_SSL_CA_File = ,
Master_SSL_CA_Path = ,
Master_SSL_Cert = ,
Master_SSL_Cipher = ,
Master_SSL_Key = ,
Seconds_Behind_Master = 0,
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert = No,
Last_IO_Errno = 0,
Last_IO_Error = ,
Last_SQL_Errno = 0,
Last_SQL_Error = ,
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids = ,
Master_Server_Id = 1,
Master_SSL_Crl = ,
Master_SSL_Crlpath = ,
Using_Gtid = No,
Gtid_IO_Pos = ,
Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids = ,
Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids = ,
Parallel_Mode = optimistic,
SQL_Delay = 0,
SQL_Remaining_Delay = null,
Slave_SQL_Running_State = Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates,
Slave_DDL_Groups = 3208,
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups = 7271,
Slave_Transactional_Groups = 107387


SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'replicate%';

Variable_name = replicate_annotate_row_events,
Value = ON

Variable_name = replicate_do_db,
Value = sandbox_joomla1

Variable_name = replicate_do_table,
Value = 

Variable_name = replicate_events_marked_for_skip,
Value = REPLICATE

Variable_name = replicate_ignore_db,
Value = 

Variable_name = replicate_ignore_table,
Value = 

Variable_name = replicate_wild_do_table,
Value = 

Variable_name = replicate_wild_ignore_table,
Value = 


I've searched online and tried the solutions that seemed plausible with no success.
I've waited overnight for changes to appear on the slave with nothing happening.

This would be better asked on [dba.se]

Recommend reading KB Setting up replication. Likely cause isserver_id is the same on both servers (or less likely based on binlog offset is log-bin not enabled on master ). recommend not doing replicate_do_db=X,  see replication filters, and let it replicate everything.

Removing the replicate_do_db filter immediately fixed my issue. I do have log-bin enabled on the master, didn't think to include that in my question.  Thanks for the help.
